# Using the count(*) function with multiple subquery tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery

I have been tasked with finding the following: "How many employee use the most expensive computer, in terms of the total cost of software package installed on the computer?"

I have been able to find the Primary keys of the employees associated with the most expensive computer using:

```
With table3 as  
(select comp from PC where tagnum in
(select tagnum from 
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' from software
group by tagnum) as Table1
where Totalcost = 
(select max(Totalcost)'MaxTotal' 
from
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' 
from software
group by tagnum
) as Table2
)))
select empnum from PC 
where PC.comp in
 (select comp from table3 where PC.comp = table3.comp)
```

However, I am unable to find the count of the employee's with these results. Any idea how I can go about doing this?

I have attached my data below...
[image]

Comment: What would be the amount you are referring to as the most expensive?

Comment: I believe it should be 2754.9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned if your query is running fine. then you can use distinct count to get how many employees are using that computer.

```
With table3 as  
(select comp from PC where tagnum in
(select tagnum from 
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' from software
group by tagnum) as Table1
where Totalcost = 
(select max(Totalcost)'MaxTotal' 
from
(select tagnum, sum(softcost)'Totalcost' 
from software
group by tagnum
) as Table2
)))
select COUNT( Distinct empnum) from PC 
where PC.comp in
 (select comp from table3 where PC.comp = table3.comp)
```